# Writing continuosuly into a file in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to open a .txt file and write continuously for every 10 milliseconds into file using the scheduleFixedRate.

While executing the file I am getting an message showing at catch (while debugging) that:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:/storage/emulated/0/test.txt (permission denied).

I added the permission to write on the external memory. No file is created.

While executing the try after `outputstream = new FileOutputStream ( file1 );` the control is showing the message from the above above.

```
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button bt1;
    TextView text;
    Timer timer = new Timer ();
    File file1 = new File ( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory (), "Test.txt" );


    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_main );
        final Button bt1 = (Button) findViewById ( R.id.button );
        final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById ( R.id.textView );
        assert bt1 != null;
        bt1.setText ( "Start" );
        bt1.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {
                if (bt1.getText ().equals ( "Stop" )) {
                    bt1.setText ( "Start" );
                } else {
                    bt1.setText ( "Stop" );
                    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate ( task, 10, 10 );
                }
            }
        } );
    }

    TimerTask task = new TimerTask () {
        @Override
        public void run () {
            writetime ();

        }
    };

    public void writetime () {
        FileOutputStream outputstream;
        try {

            outputstream = new FileOutputStream ( file1 );
            OutputStreamWriter oswriter = new OutputStreamWriter ( outputstream );
            BufferedWriter bwriter = new BufferedWriter ( oswriter );
            bwriter.append ( "Repetition" );
            bwriter.newLine ();

            bwriter.close ();
            outputstream.close ();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }

}
```

manifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.kolla.usingtimer">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Do you launch this on a particular device or in emulator?

Comment: i checked on device but file is never created.

Comment: Could you please share your manifest file here?

Comment: i added the manifest file, can you please check. As i am instructing it to create the file in external storage is it compulsion to have an sd card in mobile or will it write to device storage. i can see the path it mentioned
"/storage/emulated/0/test.txt", there is no Test.txt file in folder "0".

Comment: Could you please check if the storage is mounted at the time of write as per [Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) sample code.

Comment: i checked the storage status using 

 public boolean StorageWritable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}




then state is showing "mounted"
state: "mounted"

but the function is returning false.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, as i am using the android marshmallow the manifest permission is not sufficient. Along with it we need to give the storage permission for the app in settings after installing the app in the phone or we can use the [run time permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). It worked and now i can create the file.